# Given competing risks, what is the probability of an event within d steps from time t?

Tags: probability, hazard, competing-risks

In competing risk analysis, we can only identify the cause-specific hazard and functions of that hazard. The cumulative incidence function (CIF) is a function of the cause-specific hazards. Because the CIF makes no assumption about the independence of competing events, much of the literature focuses on this metric. Yet what if I want to know the probability that, given you reached age $t$, you will experience an event of cause $j$ within $d$ days from time $t$? How would I calculate that quantity, and will doing so make assumptions about the independence of the competing events?

**One idea**

Suppose the starting time point of interest is $t = t_j - 1$. Simply recalculate a new CIF from $t_j$ as if it were $t = 1$, summing the product of the cause-specific hazard and survivor function. The resulting CIF shows that the probability that, given you survived to $t = t_j - 1$, you will experience an event by $t = t_j + \delta$.

Comment: If events of cause $j$ happen according to a Poisson process, then the distribution of waiting times is exponential. Is that all you need? If not some more details would help

Comment: No, this is not all I need.